# Mindstorms v2 QuickTime won’t work

Tags: mindstorms

Still trying to get Mindstorms v2 working on Windows XP SP3. QuickTime causes software not to run with error code 2095. Have tried reinstalling QT several times. Tried different versions, no change. Defragmented hard disk.

Any ideas, it is driving me crackers, yes even more crackers!

Comment: How is this question different from https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/16966/3498?

Comment: I have narrowed the problem down to just a QT problem. Originally I thought it was associated with mindstokrms but the error remains with mindstorms removed completely. I am just hoping someone has come across a solution as no links I have tried on google work.

Comment: The answer to the other question already specifically addresses QuickTime issues.

Comment: Correct but as I said in my reply to that post, I did as suggested and it still didn’t work. Hoping someone might have another idea.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working with QuickTime installed from the mindstorms folder. First, though I couldn’t find the files shown above, I did a search for all QuickTime files on C:, there were lots in various directories, and deleted them all! I reinstalled mindstorms, without QuickTime then did a separate install of QT. So far that works. The tower is not working yet but that is next when I have tried starting the computer and MS a few time to ensure the QT error has gone.
Hopefully I can relax now!

Comment: Good stuff! Glad you were able to fix it, I'll add this to my bag of tricks.

Comment: Thanks, it was an uphill struggle. Tower working now. The next job is to get the Dacta interface b working!